# How can I save multiple JSON from API like dictionaries to a file and then read it Randomly? In Python

Tags: python, json, api

This is for a game that I made and I am thinking to run API for 1000 times for category so the game can run and offline for the user. The game is a question game that takes JSON and makes the dictionaries.I know how to make text or other types of files from python and write and read from them, but can I read randomly the dictionary in it? Any help is appreciated I am new and I am trying to learn python so if the question is easy and looks stupid sorry about that. Here is how the game works now: [Quiz Game . If not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62957868/quiz-game-if-not-executing) .

Answer (score 0):

I mean, you can randomly sort the dictionary keys into a list and then have them fed into the dictionary:

```
import random

random_key_list = random.shuffle(list(dict.keys()))
for random_key in random_key_list:
  someAction(random_key)
```